# xconsole causing rsyslog to fail startup

Tags: cron, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to verify that a cronjob ran on WSL2. Sources have told me to check `/var/log/syslog`. When I navigated there, `syslog` did not exist. Sources then told me to run `service rsyslog start` to start the service. When I do so, I get this error message:

```
deverteuils@:~$ service rsyslog start
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd                                                                                mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
chown: cannot access '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory
rsyslogd: error writing pid file (creation stage)
: Permission denied
rsyslogd: run failed with error -3000 (see rsyslog.h or try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 to learn what that number means)
rsyslog startup failure: error reading "fork pipe": No such file or directory
                                                                                                              [ OK ]
```

I then made the change mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/980985/how-to-prevent-rsyslog-from-requiring-dev-xconsole?newreg=9ce24d097f4645259dc2f382fe1cd20f) to my `etc/init.d/rsyslog` file. However it did not do the trick:

```
deverteuils@:/etc/init.d$ service rsyslog start
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd                                                                                rsyslogd: error writing pid file (creation stage)
: Permission denied
rsyslogd: run failed with error -3000 (see rsyslog.h or try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 to learn what that number means)
rsyslog startup failure: error reading "fork pipe": No such file or directory
                                                                                                              [ OK ]
```

I also tried making the change mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/qnL52yym7sw?pli=1) to no avail.

My next thought is to just install xconsole, but I'm not having luck with that either and at this point I've spent a lot of time on the issue.

My question is: how can I start up rsyslog without using xconsole and/or download xconsole to my machine?

For reference

```
deverteuils@:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
```

```
deverteuils@:/etc/init.d$ cat rsyslog
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rsyslog
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $time
# Required-Stop:     umountnfs $time
# X-Stop-After:      sendsigs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: enhanced syslogd
# Description:       Rsyslog is an enhanced multi-threaded syslogd.
#                    It is quite compatible to stock sysklogd and can be
#                    used as a drop-in replacement.
### END INIT INFO

#
# Author: Michael Biebl <biebl@debian.org>
#

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="enhanced syslogd"
NAME=rsyslog

RSYSLOGD=rsyslogd
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
PIDFILE=/run/rsyslogd.pid

SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Define LSB log_* functions.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   other if daemon could not be started or a failure occured
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS
}

do_stop()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been stopped
        #   1 if daemon was already stopped
        #   other if daemon could not be stopped or a failure occurred
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
}

#
# Tell rsyslogd to close all open files
#
do_rotate() {
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
}

create_xconsole() {
        XCONSOLE=/dev/xconsole
        if [ "$(uname -s)" != "Linux" ]; then
                XCONSOLE=/run/xconsole
                ln -sf $XCONSOLE /dev/xconsole
        fi
        if [ ! -e $XCONSOLE ]; then
                mknod -m 640 $XCONSOLE p
                chown root:adm $XCONSOLE
                [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon $XCONSOLE
        fi
}

sendsigs_omit() {
        OMITDIR=/run/sendsigs.omit.d
        mkdir -p $OMITDIR
        ln -sf $PIDFILE $OMITDIR/rsyslog
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$RSYSLOGD"
        #create_xconsole
        do_start
        case "$?" in
                0) sendsigs_omit
                   log_end_msg 0 ;;
                1) log_progress_msg "already started"
                   log_end_msg 0 ;;
                *) log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac

        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$RSYSLOGD"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                1) log_progress_msg "already stopped"
                   log_end_msg 0 ;;
                *) log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac

        ;;
  rotate)
        log_daemon_msg "Closing open files" "$RSYSLOGD"
        do_rotate
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
  try-restart)
        $0 status >/dev/null 2>&1 && $0 restart
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON $RSYSLOGD && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|rotate|restart|force-reload|try-restart|status}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

Comment: starting and stopping of system services requires root privileges

Comment: @steeldriver that didn't work either: 

sudo service rsyslog start


[sudo] password for deverteuils:
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd        rsyslogd: set SO_TIMESTAMP failed on '/dev/log': Invalid argument [v8.2001.0]
rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): No such file or directory.
rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
[ OK ]

Comment: Did you actually check (`service rsyslog status`)? Did you try writing something to the log (`logger 'test syslg'`) and looking in the log file?

Comment: @steeldriver I ran that command before hand and it said the service was not running. However, after running it again, it says that the service is running. Not sure which one of my commands did it. Thank you!